# Display SMS message in TextView

Tags: android, textview, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing a small app that when the phone receives SMS messages. It will show the sender phone number and the SMS body in a `TextView`. I have an SMS `BoardcastReceiver` and an `Activity`.

Here is my SMS Listener.

```java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    BroadcastNewSms ourSMS;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                            .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReciver", "senderNum: " + senderNum
                            + ", message: " + message);
                    //ourSMS.getSmsDetails(senderNum, message);
                    // Show SMS notification
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "
                            + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end of for loop
            } // bundle

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("SmsReciver", "Exception smsReciver" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity:

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BroadcastNewSms extends Activity {

    TextView SMSm;
    String phoneNumber1;
    String SMSBody1;

    public void getSmsDetails(String phoneNumber, String SMSBody) {
        phoneNumber1 = phoneNumber;
        SMSBody1 = SMSBody;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SMSm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSmsBody);

         SMSm.setText("Phone Number: " + phoneNumber1 + " " + "SMS: " +
         SMSBody1);

    }

}
```

Here is my Manifest:

```xml
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="kobi.avshalom.recivesms.BroadcastNewSms"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="kobi.avshalom.recivesms.IncomingSms" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>  
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
```

Comment: But What is your issue / Error ?

Comment: @Prince please debug. No questions asked

Comment: @SherifelKhatib what ? OP doesnt specify issue so i ask about this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For anyone to be able to help you, you need to ask your question with clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BroadcastNewSms activity declare `getSmsDetails` static:
`public static void getSmsDetails(String phoneNumber, String SMSBody)`

In IncomingSms replace `//ourSMS.getSmsDetails(senderNum, message);`
with `BroadcastNewSms.getSmsDetails(senderNum, message);`

I also suggest you change getSmsDetails to setSmsDetails

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PopupWindow ? 
You can show an popup like this:

```
private PopupWindow popupWindow;
```

....

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_root_element), true);
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // Display the popup window
popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

To dismiss the popup window you must call

```
// Close the popup window
popupWindow.dismiss();
```

You can put this in a timer(if you want automatic dismiss) or you can attach the event to an button in popup window's layout.

To access elements inside the popup window's layout you can use:

```
popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_widget);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: The layout for the PopupWidnow can have only a TextView widget inside.